# ASP.NET MVC Web API & StructureMap: "does not have a default constructor"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, structuremap, asp.net-web-api

I configured an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API project to use StructureMap 2.6.2.0 as described in [this post](http://notebookheavy.com/2012/06/25/setup-structuremap-with-asp-net-web-api-release-candidate/), but accessing `/api/parts` returns the following error despite explicitly calling `StructuremapMvc.Start();` in `Application_Start()`:

```
{
  "ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentException",
  "Message": "Type 'MyProject.Web.Controllers.PartsController' does not have
              a default constructor",
  "StackTrace": "   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)\r\n 
                    at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)\r\n   
                    at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)"
}
```

I implemented `IDependencyResolver` and `IDependencyScope` and set the Web API dependency resolver as follows in `~/App_Start/StructureMapMvc.cs`:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
    new StructureMapHttpDependencyResolver(container);
```

Why is Web API still complaining about a default consturctor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out the error description is just really bad. StructureMap is being called, but cannot inject a dependent constructor parameter due to a missing connection string.

Here's how I fixed it in `IoC.cs`:

```
x.For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(MongoRepository<>))
    .CtorDependency<string>("connectionString")
    .Is(yourConnectionString);
```

I was doing this (incorrectly):

```
x.For<IRepository<SomeEntity>>().Use<MongoRepository<SomeEntity>>();
```

There really should be a way to output inner StructureMap exceptions when they occur in the Web API.

Comment: Thanks for this. I just got burned by the same terribly misleading error message.

Comment: If you make your constructor take no arguments and instead use `ObjectFactory.GetInstance<>` then structuremap will give you a more helpful error message. Then change it back once you've fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that the DI is not called to provide a controller instance but I don't know why. Have you tried setting a debug break point in the structure map code provided by the post (i.e. the code that lives on github) to make sure that it is called?

Answer (score 0):

If you hit this error on some controllers, but not others it is likely a different issue.

To get better exception information, add a try / catch in the GetService method override in your implementation of IDependencyScope and set a break point in the catch block. You'll be able to get better debug info.

I know OP already got an answer, this is just for anyone else who stumbles across this and finds it useful.